# How can I add a point in xy line in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

I have a line chart with 2 lines. But I want to show the point where two lines are overlapping. It will be nicer if I show the point with lines additionally.

```
Q<-8
xdata <- seq(1,Q*2,1)
HCdata <- matrix(1,1)
OCdata <- matrix(1,1)

for (i in xdata) {

  OC<-(100/i)*100
  HC<-(i/2)*20*20
  HCdata[i]<- HC
  OCdata[i]<- OC

}

holdingcost <- data.frame(holdingcost=HCdata)
orderingcost <- data.frame(orderingcost=OCdata)
xx<-cbind(holdingcost,orderingcost)
y <- ggplot(xx, aes(xdata)) 
y1 <- y +  geom_line(size=1,aes(y=holdingcost, colour = "holdingcost")) 
y1 <- y1 + geom_line(size=1,aes(y=orderingcost, colour = "orderingcost"))
```

Comment: For future reference, you can create your data frame without a loop as follows: `xx = data.frame(xdata, holdingcost = xdata/2 * 20 * 20, orderingcost = 100/xdata * 100)`.

Answer (score 0):

Find the x value where they are closest to equal:

```
eq <- xx[which.min(abs(xx$holdingcost - xx$orderingcost)), ]
```

Add the point:

```
y1 + geom_point(data = eq, aes(y = holdingcost), size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work for higher values.

Q<-2.3
xdata <- seq(1,Q*2,1)
HCdata <- matrix(1,1)
OCdata <- matrix(1,1)

for (i in xdata) {
  
  OC<-(1000/i)*100
  HC<-(i/2)*50*750
  HCdata[i]<- HC
  OCdata[i]<- OC
  
}

check with that. By the way thanks for helping!

Comment: The problem isn't the high values, it's the fact that you only have 4 values, and the point goes to the closest one. You;ll have to do interpolation to fix that, or change your `for` loop (which you don't need at all, as mentioned by @eipi10).